# Can't get the Speech Recognizer and a KinectRegion to work together

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction

The Kinect SDK 1.8 has a menu demo with a tile list that uses the **KinectSensorChooser** and a **KinectRegion** and it works great, the SDK also have a speech recognition sample but it uses a **KinectSensor** object directly, no sensor chooser.

I wanted to **combine both KinectRegion GUI and Audio** but can't get it to work, there are no exceptions at all but it won't respond.

When I bind a Microsoft.Speech recognizer to a **KinectSensorChooser.Kinect** property the speech recognition event *never triggers*, as if it doesn't receive any audio.

When I bind a **KinectRegion** to a raw **KinectSensor** object the region doesn't work, meaning *it won't display the hand cursor nor respond to hand movements*.

The samples that I'm talking about are: Controls Basic WPF (C#) and Speech Basics-WPF (C#).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

**Binding the Speech Recognition Engine to a KinectSensorChooser - Doesn't work**

```
speechEngine.SetInputToAudioStream(this.sensorChooser.Kinect.AudioSource.Start(), new    SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));
```

**Binding the Speech Recognition Engine to a raw KinectSensor - Works**

```
speechEngine.SetInputToAudioStream(this.sensor.AudioSource.Start(), new    SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));
```

**Binding a KinectRegion to a KinectSensor - Doesn't work**

```
var regionSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensor };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.kinectRegion, KinectRegion.KinectSensorProperty, regionSensorBinding);
```

**Binding a KinectRegion to a KinectSensorChooser - Works**

```
var regionSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.kinectRegion, KinectRegion.KinectSensorProperty, regionSensorBinding);
```

Comment: In what order are you initializing audio and skeleton tracking?  See the Kinect for Windows Known Issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435682.aspx - "Audio is not processed if skeleton stream is enabled after starting audio capture"

Answer (score 0):

I kept the **KinectSensorChooser** initialization at the main method of the Window (creator) and moved the speech audio initialization code to the Window_Openeded event and it worked.
I suppose the timing was not good enough to initialize the sensor and audio during the window creation.
Thank you